# Missing "policy" stated by Yahoo since DMARC implementation?

Tags: yahoo, content-security-policy, dmarc

Since the implementation of DMARC on our server we get feedback reports from Yahoo, stating we do not publish a "policy" which therefore cannot be evaluated (to my understanding).
However the same report later states "pass" for SPF and DKIM for the respective domains and IP address.

What kind of "policy" would be required and where would we publish it?

This is, what we're getting:

```
<policy_published>  
    <domain>domain1.at</domain>
    <adkim>r</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>none</p>
    <pct>100</pct>
  </policy_published>
    <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>88.198.xx.xx</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>domain1.at</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>domain2.at</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>domain2.at</domain> 
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>88.198.xx.xx</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>domain1.at</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>domain1.at</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>domain1.at</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Since the implementation of DMARC on our server we get feedback reports from Yahoo, stating we do not publish a "policy" which therefore cannot be evaluated (to my understanding).

If you're getting this from the XML excerpt you shared, are you assuming the `<p>none</p>` is stating there is no policy published?
In this case none **IS** the policy that is published. If your TXT record at `_dmarc.domain1.at` has a tag=value of `p=none`, it is telling receiving servers that you're using DMARC in reporting only mode. `p=quarantine` or `p=reject` would actually request email authentication enforcement.

In the example you can see that the first record you can see that SPF and DKIM are passing on `domain2.at`. However, it is failing DMARC because there is no alignment with `domain1.at`, which is used as the `header.from`. In the second record, there is alignment and DMARC is PASS.

If both emails are legit, you have some work in front of you before you can set a `p=quarantine` or `p=reject` policy.